# spring security role bases panel + jsf 2

Tags: jsf, spring-security

how I can make role based panel for user with jsf and spring security? I'm new with those technologies.

How can I check role of the user using SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?

Ok I see now I can use #{SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.authorities} 
but how can I based on list returned by previous instruction check if it contains admin role?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Spring [Security Facelets Tag Library](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html). 
Also, you need to understand the basic concepts at [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html).